# null terminate an array of strings

Tags: c, linux, string, null, exec

I am trying to figure out how to get my array of strings from `get_arguments` to `NULL` terminate, or if that isn't the issue to function in my `execv` call.

```
char ** get_arguments(const char * string) {
    char * copy = strdup(string);
    char * remove_newline = "";
    for(;;) {
        remove_newline = strpbrk(copy, "\n\t");
        if (remove_newline) {
            strcpy(remove_newline, "");
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }   
    char (* temp)[16] = (char *) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    char * token = strtok(copy, " ");
    strcpy(temp[0], token); 
    int i = 1;
    while (token && (token = strtok(NULL, " "))) {
        strcpy(temp[i], token);
        i++;
    }
    char * new_null;
    //new_null = NULL; 
    //strcpy(temp[i], new_null);
    if(!temp[i]) printf("yup\n");
    int c = 0;
    for ( ; c <= i; c++) {
        printf("%s ", temp[c]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I am trying to read in a string, space separated, similar to `find ./ -name *.h`.  I am trying to input them into `execv`.

```
char (* arguments)[16] = (char **) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
```

//...numerous lines of unrelated code

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    arguments = get_arguments(input_string);
    char * para[] = {"find", "./","-name", "*.h", NULL};
    execv("/usr/bin/find", (char * const *) arguments);
    //printf("%s\n", arguments[0]);
    printf("\nexec failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); //ls -l -R
    exit(-1);
}
```

When I swap `arguments` in the `execv` call for `para` it works as intended, but trying to call with `arguments` returns `exec failed: Bad address`.  If I remove the `NULL` from `para` I get the same issue.  I've tried `strcpy(temp, (char *) NULL)`, the version you see commented out in `get_arguments`, and a number of other things that I can't recall in their entirety, and my program ranges from `Segmentation fault` to failure to compile from attempting to `strcpy` NULL.

Changing the declarations of arguments and temp to `char ** arguments = (char *) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));` ``char ** temp = (char *) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));`clears up`warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type`but causes segfault on all calls to`get_arguments`.

Comment: I am most confused because most places I read say that unused space in a declared array space is defaulted to null, but it fails the `if(!temp[i]) printf("yup\n");` test under all conditions I have attempted.

Comment: You can remove the `(char *)` cast in front of that `malloc()`, for one thing.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared up `warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type`.  Odd that is a convention I've seen used repeatedly.  Are there situations where that explicit type is required?

Comment: Not in C. Some people are very adamant that you should never cast a `malloc()`, others think that it is OK when it makes your code clearer. You were getting a warning because you were casting the return value of `malloc()` to `char *`, but assigning that value to `char **`. Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
char* temp[256]; // an array of 256 char*'s
char * token = strtok(copy, " ");
temp[0] = strdup(token);
int i = 1;
while (token && (token = strtok(NULL, " "))) {
    temp[i] = strdup(token);
    i++;
}
temp[i] = NULL;
```